# How to solve $e^{ix} +e^{2ix} + e^{3ix}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

how do you solve $e^{ix} +e^{2ix} + e^{3ix}=0$. I was thinking of pulling out a factor $e^{ix}$ and then using $u=e^{ix}$ because you have a quadratic equation then. \

But I am not sure.

Comment: So how did you solve the quadratic equation?

Comment: by pulling out e^ix and then using abc formula. But I am stuck now

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Do you have the quadratic equation?  Write down the quadratic equation in your post.

Comment: e^ix(1+e^ix + e^2ix)

Comment: So $1+u+u^2=0$ in your terminology. Hence $0=\frac{u^3-1}{u-1}$. So ???

Answer (score 3):

Factor $e^{2ix}$ obtaining
$$
e^{2ix}(e^{-ix}+1+e^{ix})=0\\
e^{2ix}(2\cos x+1)=0\\
$$
but $e^{2ix}\neq0$

Comment: so cos x= -1/2    x= 2/3 pi +2pi k

Comment: @RobinBarels: yes, also $-2\pi/3+2\pi k$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If you denote $\omega$ one of the non-real cubic root of unity, it is well-known that
$$1+\omega+\omega^2=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$t + t^2 + t^3 = 0 \,\,(e^{ix} = t) $$
$$ t = 0 \;\; or  \;\; 1+t+t^2 = 0$$
$$ t = 0, w, w^2 $$

$$ w = \frac{(-1 + i\sqrt{3})}{2}$$
$$ e^{ix}  = 0, w, w^2$$

we know that, (  $ e^{ix} \not= 0 $ ) , hence ignore the first root for $t$ ; now we can write $ w $ and $w ^2$ in polar form to find $x$ (note that if you can find principal solutions for $x$ ; that turns out to be $ x_p = \frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{4\pi}{3} $ then any $x = x_p + 2n\pi \,\,(n \in \mathbb{N})$ is also a solution ! )

Comment: yes I already have e^ix= -1/2 +isqrt(3)/ 2

Comment: Except $e^{ix}$ can't equal zero, so we can discard that.

Comment: but e^ix is equal to (-1+sqrt(3))/2 right?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work.  The quadratic equation is $t^2+t+1$, with $t=e^{ix}$.

Using the quadratic formula, we get $t=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt3i}2$.

Now $x=-i\ln t$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=e^{\mathrm ix}$ to get the equation

$$u+u^2+u^3=0,$$

which you can factor to get

$$u(u^2+u+1)=0.$$

$u=0$ is impossible, so it reduces to $u^2+u+1=0$, the solutions of which are
$$u\in\{e^{\frac{2\pi\mathrm i}{3}},e^{\frac{4\pi\mathrm i}{3}}\}.$$

Now you just have to find the solutions to the two equations

$$e^{\mathrm ix}=e^{\frac{2\pi\mathrm i}{3}},\\
e^{\mathrm ix}=e^{\frac{4\pi\mathrm i}{3}}.$$

The only thing to be careful about is that you should note that $e^{\mathrm ix}$ is periodic, but otherwise the solutions should be clear from here.

Comment: How do you go from u^2 +u +1=0 to the two solutions

Comment: Shouldnt it be e^ix= sqrt(1/2) e^2pi/3 i

Comment: From knowing that $u^3-1=(u-1)(u^2+u+1)$, which means that roots of $u^2+u+1$ are roots of $u^3-1$. Those are the cubic roots of unity, which can be expressed as exponential functions in the way I did.